# icCube : how to show that a Big Widget is loading?

Tags: iccube-reporting

Using iccube 5.2, we developped a custom widget that needs quite BIG data download...

Unfortunately, when loading a report containing this widget, nothing is shown on the screen until it is loaded and users may think nothing happens...

How could I advise the user it is working, and he just has to wait ?

Answer (score 1):

There are predefined styles for such case.

```
<div class="ic3-fixed-layout-box ic3-loading" style="width:200px; height:200px">
   <div class="ic3-loading-div-back"></div>
</div>
```

This html will result in 200x200 px box with loading animation and blur effect.

So, to see loading effect class `.ic3-loading` should be added to the widget's parent container (with class `.ic3-fixed-layout-box`) while request is loading.

Check that your widget spawns with these classes before request send, and on request success just remove `.ic3-loading` class from parent element just like it is done for ic3 widgets.